# airflow successeful task rerun before moving to another task

Tags: python, airflow

I am new to airflow and i am trying to have a task that is running every minute run alone for a while before going forward with other tasks. So my dag has a schedule interval of every minute and i want to run a task for 15 minutes before moving on. The task in question is filling up a file with data every minute and i need to get 15 minutes worth of data to analyze.

I tried with

```
def sleep_15_minutes():
    time.sleep(900)

delay_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='sleep_15_mintes',
    dag=my_dag,
    python_callable=sleep_15_minutes
)

task1 >> delay_task >>task2
```

But it doesn't work.

Any idea please ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use TimeDeltaSensor

```
start_dag = EmptyOperator(task_id="start")
end_dag = EmptyOperator(task_id="end")
delay_task = TimeDeltaSensor(
    task_id='wait_15_min',
    delta=timedelta(seconds=60 * 15))
start_dag >> delay_task >> end_dag
```